# Extracting integers from a query string

Tags: html, c, forms, query-string

I am creating a program that can make mysql transactions through C and html.

I have this query string
`query = -id=103&-id=101&-id=102&-act=Delete`

Extracting "Delete" by sscanf isn't that hard, but I need help extracting the integers and putting them in an array of int `id[]`. The number of `-id` entries can vary depending on how many checkboxes were checked in the html form.

I've been searching for hours but haven't found any applicable solution; or I just did not understand them. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strstr` and `atoi` to extract the numbers in a loop, like this:

```
char *query = "-id=103&-id=101&-id=102&-act=Delete";
char *ptr = strstr(query, "-id=");
if (ptr) {
    ptr += 4;
    int n = atoi(ptr);
    printf("%d\n", n);
    for (;;) {
        ptr = strstr(ptr, "&-id=");
        if (!ptr) break;
        ptr += 5;
        int n = atoi(ptr);
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }            
}
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/pSquQA).

Comment: It's specific only to capturing "id's" ... and you can simplify a bit (by looking for "-id" instead of "&-id") ... but I like it :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `strtok` or a better solution, to tokenize this string with `&` and `=` as tokens.

Take a look at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) for more information and an example.

This is the output you would get from strtok

```
Output:

Splitting string "- This, a sample string." into tokens:
This
a
sample
string
```

Once you figure out how to split them, the next hurdle is to convert the numbers from strings to `int`s. For this you need to look at [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) or its safer more robust cousin [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/)

Comment: You should probably mention `strtol` as that is part of his question too.

Comment: If I use `strtok`, would it then be possible to distribute the integers over to the int array?

Comment: @Exphyre `strtok` is used to split the string up into the pieces, it is then up to you to find the integers among those pieces, and then convert them and store them into the array

Answer (score 0):

Most likely I would write a small lexical scanner to tackle the task. Meaning, I would analyze the string one character at a time, according to a regular expression representing the set of possible inputs.